# What's the best way to end an email/letter?

Tags: writing, email, greetings

We end an email with several options. I find 'Regards' the best one. I feel anything other than this reflects affection than greeting! See the example:

1. Sincerely yours (Yes, I don't pay heed to anyone else!)
2. Yours sincerely (I'm all yours. I'm pretty sincere!)
3. Truly yours (My soul is yours, truly!)

Is there any alternate way to end the mail? Using 'Regards' all time is not done!

Comment: 1. I wouldn't read too much into standard closings. They are often used merely because they are commonly used. 2. I think you should change the title of your question; there is no "best way" to end an email. 3. I have no problem with someone always or consistently using 'Regards,' (or 'Cheers!' or 'Toodles,' or whatever else they like to use); sometimes it breeds a comforting sense of consistency in regular correspondence. 4. If you think 'Truly yours' is too intimate, try looking up some of the doozies from 200 years ago! _Your most faithful and humble servant_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider simply *sincerely*. *Sincerely yours* does sound a bit off to me for professional correspondence; I might indeed be sincere, but it's doubtful I'm *theirs*. *Regards* has always sounded a bit stiff to me, but I wouldn't look twice at it; it's common enough. Even *sincerely* sounds strange to me for email; I would certainly recommend it for a handwritten letter, though.

You've got to consider the difference in levels of formality between email and letters. For a letter, this would look perfectly fine to me:

> Dear Jane,
>
> [body of letter]
>
> Sincerely,
>
> [name]

But in an email we're generally much less formal, both in closing and opening. I'd take off the *dear* and use something less formal for the closing. For example:

> Jane,
>
> [body of email]
>
> Thanks,
>
> [name]

But plenty of people do use *regards*, and no one is going to think it strange if you do. Sometimes emails begin with *hi* as well. There's really nothing wrong with always using the same closing, either, so if *regards* works for you, use it! In fact I think most people do use the same closing most of the time. Considering my own email habits, I think I tend to do one of three things: 1) If I'm just sending along information, I don't use a closing at all; I simply end with my name. 2) If I'm requesting something of someone, or thanking them for something they've already done, I'll use *thanks*. 3) If I've written a significantly longer-than-usual email or am requesting significant effort on the recipient's part, I might end with *thank you for your time*. In a letter, I pretty much always use *sincerely*. In my experience, most people do. But email varies quite widely, so I wouldn't worry about this too much!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I liked the three ways you mentioned in the last para.